# Tablet for use with Lightroom 5

Tags: equipment-recommendation, lightroom

Any suggestions for a graphic tablet (PC compatible) for a novice user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wacom tablets seem to be standard.  I got a CTH-480 for under $100 and it has proven capable of handling all tasks I've attempted in Lightroom and Photoshop, including following tutorials led by guys with the highest-end digitizer tablets.

Comment: Thank you!  I very much appreciate the time you took to assist me!